# Comparing width and height of uploaded picture

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a file input (picture) and I want to set its `div`'s `class` depending on what is bigger: its `width` or its `height`.

My code is not working (only the last `if` statement), the `div`'s class never changes, regardless to the uploaded image.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="blah" class="profilePic">
            <img src="profilkep.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="file" onchange="previewFile()">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my JavaScript:

```
function previewFile(){
    var preview = document.querySelector('img'); //selects the query named img
    var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]; //sames as here
    var reader  = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function () {
        preview.src = reader.result;
    }

    if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL
    } else {
        preview.src = "";
    }

    if (file.width < file.height) {
        document.getElementById("blah").setAttribute("class", "blahblah");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("blah").setAttribute("class", "profilePic");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two same IDs `blah`. All ids need to be unique.
`file.width` and `file.height` are always undefined. Here is the fix:

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="blah">
      <img id="profileImage" src="profilkep.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="file" onchange="previewFile()">
  </div>
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function previewFile(){
        var preview = document.querySelector('img'); //selects the query named img
        var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]; //sames as here
        var reader  = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function () {
          preview.src = reader.result;
          var imageWidth = $('#profileImage').width();
          var imageHeight = $('#profileImage').height();
          if (imageWidth < imageHeight) {
          console.log('width < height');
          document.getElementById("blah").setAttribute("class", "blahblah");
        } else {
          console.log('width > height');
          document.getElementById("blah").setAttribute("class", "profilePic");
        }
        }

        if (file) {
          reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL
        } else {
          preview.src = "";
        }

      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, good point, I removed the second one, but it's still not working.

Comment: What do you mean by undefined?

Comment: look at my answer now, it's working. file.width is undefined in the time when you asked for him

Comment: Tell me where is the problem now if you have it ?

Comment: Oh yes, thank you! I just haven't seen the first part of it.

Comment: Just a little problem. When I change a "tall" picture to a "flat" one, I see that the class changes, but its style is still like a tall ones. I have to upload another image, so that the style changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. Here's a working snippet

```js
function previewFile(){
        var preview = document.querySelector('img'); //selects the query named img
        var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]; //sames as here
        var reader  = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function () {
          preview.src = reader.result;
        }

        if (file) {
          reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL
        } else {
          preview.src = "";
        }

        if (file.width < file.height) {
          document.getElementById("blah").setAttribute("class", "blahblah");
        } else {
          document.getElementById("blah").setAttribute("class", "profilePic");
        }
      }
```

```css
.blahblah {
border: 1px solid red;
}

.profilePic {
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="blah" class="profilePic">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MxPGcXu.gif" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" id="blah">
        <input type="file" onchange="previewFile()">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: But in your example the picture has a 1px solid **blue** border, but it should have a 1px solid **red** one.